# PostgreSQL know table hierarchy

Tags: postgresql, migration

Is there a way to know the parent - child relations (in terms of foreign keys) of all the tables in postgresql database? We are planning a full database migration using AWS DMS, we need specify in what order we can migrate our tables.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-foreign-key-constraint-error/) suggests to disable constraint checks:

> If the target is a PostgreSQL-compatible database, then you can see foreign key violation errors during the CDC phase. To resolve this error, set the [session_replication_role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SESSION-REPLICATION-ROLE) parameter to replica.

If you really want to specify the table order manually, use any of the queries from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1152260/11654) to get a list; for example:

```
SELECT
    tc.table_schema, 
    tc.table_name, 
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name
FROM 
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
    USING (constraint_name, table_schema)
WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```